# How to bulk insert Array in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am ingesting data in snowflake using the following command:

```
 copy into ArrayTable from (select $1, array_construct($2),array_construct($3) 

 from @ArrayTable_stage/ArrayTable-1-1.csv.gz) 
    
 file_format = (TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='|' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='\"')
```

But the **array_construct()** is not feasible for  insertion of multiple tables since I have to manually specify columns which are of ARRAY datatype.

What is the alternative method for bulk insertion of Arrays in snowflake?

Comment: How are you expecting fields in a csv file to be identified as arrays if you are not going to specify them?  Why is you specifying them not feasible?

Comment: The code I have posted only accepts tables which have 3 columns of array datatypes. So if I have a table with more than 3 columns, I have to manually update the code each time, So I want to know if there is any method which can automatically select all array columns in the table.

Comment: According to your posted code, you are importing from a csv file. So my original question still stands: how are you expecting the process to differentiate a text field in your file that you want to treat as an array from a text field you want to treat as just a text field?

Comment: Yes, I want the array to be just treated as a text field. For example `1 | ['1112223333','6195551234']  |  [[11,12]]`  should be stored as it is in the snowflake table.

Comment: But the whole point of your question is that you want it to be treated as an array, not a text field? Which is it? Do you want the data loaded into a varchar column as text or loaded into a variant column as an array? If you just want to treat it a text then what’s the problem - you just do SELECT $1, $2, $3, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this article would help or you have already seen it:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-an-INSERT-statement-to-add-an-ARRAY-column-to-the-table

I am also following your question. Just to see what you are trying is achievable in snowflake dynamically or we always have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Could you share some sample data of what your source/stage looks like.

But, creating the table with the columns as `Variant` datatype should work for what you are looking to do. You then should not need to do the `array_construct()`

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html

Comment: Sample Data is : `1    ['1112223333','6195551234']     [[11,12]]`

Comment: And using Variant datatype gives me the error `Copy to table failed: 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: ('1112223333','6195551234')` when inserting the data.